# Vue click event on multiple td elements exception on first and last

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table, onclick

I want to use a **click event** in my table to go to the **detailpage** of the clicked row with the **exception** on the **first and last td element**.

**Example:**

```
<tr v-for="(row, key) in $rows" :key="row.id">
  <td>*Input checkbox*</td>
  <td>{{ row.user.type }}</td>
  <td>{{ date | moment('MMMM') }}</td>
  <td>{{ row.customer.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ row.user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ row.total }}</td>
  <td>*Icon to archive*</td>
</tr>
```

What I can't use because of exception on first and last element:

```
<tr @click="detailPage(row.user.id)" v-for="(row, key) in $rows" :key="row.id">
```

What I don't want to use because of repeating code:

```
<tr v-for="(row, key) in $rows" :key="row.id">
  <td>*Input checkbox*</td>
  <td @click="detailPage(row.user.id)">{{ row.user.type }}</td>
  <td @click="detailPage(row.user.id)">{{ date | moment('MMMM') }}</td>
  <td @click="detailPage(row.user.id)">{{ row.customer.name }}</td>
  <td @click="detailPage(row.user.id)">{{ row.user.name }}</td>
  <td @click="detailPage(row.user.id)">{{ row.total }}</td>
  <td>*Icon to archive*</td>
</tr>
```

What I tried but didn't trigger the click event:

```
<tr v-for="(row, key) in $rows" :key="row.id">
  <td>*Input checkbox*</td>
  <template @click="detailPage(row.user.id)">
    <td>{{ row.user.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ date | moment('MMMM') }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.customer.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.total }}</td>
    <td>*Icon to archive*</td>
  </template>
</tr>
```

How I could solve with JQuery:

```
$('table#tbl > tbody > tr > td').not(':first').not(':last').click(function() {
  // detailpage
})
```

**Method from click event**

```
methods: {
  detailPage (id) {
    this.$router.push({path: `/timesheets/view/${id}`})
  },
```

Is there a right way in Vue without repeating code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add this event modifier on the td element you don't want to trigger with the click :

```
v-on:click.stop=""
```

or just :

```
@click.stop
```

and leave the @click on the tr element.

You can check the documentation for more informations :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 1
  },
  methods:{
  add(){
  this.message++;
  }
  }
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr @click="add()">
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td v-on:click.stop="">Visitor n° {{message}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, or simply `@click.stop`. +1